# How do I remove variable randomly using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to find a way to remove variable from certain div on the web using jquery. **This does not involve using array.** If I can do so with using `fadeIn()` or `search()` and `remove()`, that's even better.

```
var something = '#img' + count;
```

on the web, images will be added to div as time passes (using `setTimeout`). Those images have been assigned to variable (`something`) and I need to find a way to remove it from certain div on the web. It can be hide, remove, whatever, **it has to disappear from user's view randomly (both time and which image will disappear).**

Thanks for help and your time in advance.

my function code:

```
var count = 0;

function foo() {
  var xPos = xPosition();
  var yPos = yPosition();
  var someTime;

  $("div").append('<img id="Img" ' + count + ' src = "img.png" style="top:' + yPos + 'px; left: ' + xPos + 'px; " />');
  var something = "#Img" + count;
  someTime = setTimeout('foo()', randInterval());
  $(something).hide();
  count++;

  if (timeRemaining == 0) {
    clearTimeout(someTime);
    return;
  }
```

Comment: Doesn't `$(something).hide()` do what you want?

Comment: I thought so but something else is missing and it doesn't work. hide() does nothing.

Comment: You need to show your code, there's no way we can guess what you're doing wrong.

Comment: added function. Sorry but this is a game code so rather huge.

Comment: Post the code here, not just a fiddle link.

Comment: `something` is the ID of the image that you just appended, so you're hiding it right after you append it. Is that what you really want?

Comment: uh, not right after. well, `something` is continuously being added every 2 secs but they need to disappear randomly too. It's a whack-a-mole game and the moles need to disappear if user doesn't click in time.

Comment: @VaygrEmpire Don't keep your game state in a sea of web page elements. Keep track of the elements when you add them in javascript data structures, then you can randomly select them with obvious means. You can `.push` new elements into an array when you create them, and `.splice(randomInRange, 1).remove()` to pick one out for removal

Comment: It's still not clear what you're trying to do. Do you want to remove the previous image when you add the new image? Why don't you just change the CSS of the image if you want to move it to a different position?

Comment: @Barmar not really. RIght now my images are being added every 2 secs and user need to click in order to score points and when he does that image disappears. But since there are so many images being added I want some of the images to be removed before user clicks them (say, every 3 secs 1 random image will disappear). I don't want to move it to a different position, but I want it to be permanently removed from div space. In a way, yes I want some of previous images to disappear but not all of them. I'm sorry again if I'm giving too much confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give all the images a class. You can then use `$(".class").length()` to get the number of images, pick a random number in this range, and delete that element with `.eq()`.

```
function addImage() {
    var xPos = xPosition();
    var yPos = yPosition();
    $("div").append($("<img>", {
        src: "img.png",
        "class": "imageclass",
        style: {
            top: yPos+"px",
            left: xPos+"px"
        }
    }));
    setTimeout(addImage, randInterval());
}
setTimeout(addImage, randInterval());

function removeImage() {
    var images = $(".imageclass");
    if (images.length) {
        var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
        images.eq(rand).remove();
    }
    setTimeout(removeImage, randInterval());
}
setTimeout(removeImage, randInterval());
```

In my code I'm using separate timers for adding and removing images. If you prefer, you could remove the `setTimeout` from `removeImage()`, and just call it from `addImage` so it will always remove an image whenever it's adding a new one.

Comment: I really appreciate the time and help you took. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please, never ever append a number to an id and piece together numbered names of things. It is unmaintainable and bad. Use `class`.

Assign a purpose or functionality to an element or elements by adding a class name to them. If you want to add information to an element, that is great, use `data-` prefix on the attribute name and it is all legal. `data-itemid` is an example.

You can query for matching elements with `var those = $('.that-class-name')`, stored for reuse. From there you can access individual elements using `those.eq(0)` through `those.eq(x.length - 1)`. For example, if you somehow knew that the 3rd one needs to be removed, then `those.eq(3).remove();`. If you want to pick through them and only select ones that match a condition, use `those.filter(callback).remove()`, where `callback` returns `true` if the element referred to by `this` should be removed. If you want to filter those with another selector, `.filter` will accept a selector too.

Is that what you meant?

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm giving confusion. The reason I can't use eq is there's no way for me to get the index number. `something` is being added every 2 secs and I can't guess which number is going to be removed. I'll not be able to use `class` for this one but thanks for letting me know.